# How are .so files used in Ubuntu

Tags: shared-library

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu and I have ported my simple game engine to linux. The engine is in a .so file and is linked to the executable.

I am unable to run my executable because it says that it cannot find the Engine.so file (when run in terminal).

So if I am developing on Ubuntu how can I get the executable to find the library were ever it is?

Second question is when distributing the application how are the .so files installed? I assume they are not just put in the same directory as the exe as in windows? so how are they installed?

Answer (score 10):

Executables search for libraries in a set of places, e.g. `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`,...  so if you do not put your `.so` file in one of these places (`/usr/local/lib` might be a good place), the executable won't run.

You can explicitly specify a set directories to search for by setting an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` containing whatever directories you like, (including your development directory for instance).

Comment: Thanks, When programs install so they put there needed libs in those folders for you?

Comment: @DavidColson Typically when you build from source, and do `./configure` `make` `make --install` (or whatever the command strings are for that make file), it has a script to automatically install to wherever it will check for the script(s) and libraries.  Although there are programs which don't install themselves anywhere correctly.

Comment: Many third-party packages make use of the second mechanism so that they can supply the appropriate versions of the libraries with their installer.